# Access a shadowed receiver

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, receiver, either, arrow-kt

I would like to combine a Kotlin extension function on some receiver class `Receiver` with arrow-kt's either comprehension. In a regular Kotlin extension function, `this` binds to the receiver object; however, the either-comprehension `EitherEffect` shadows the Receiver `this`:

```kotlin
suspend fun Receiver.myFun(param: String): Either<Throwable, String> = either {
  this.someMethod(...).bind() // Cannot access Receiver.someMethod, <this> is bound to EitherEffect
  ...
}
```

How can I access the receiver context within arrow's either-comprehension block (or any other monadic comprehension block)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue inherited from Kotlin, but you can always access outer scoped `this` by referencing it by name. Here you can access `Receiver` by referencing it by `this@myFun`.

```kotlin
suspend fun Receiver.myFun(param: String): Either<Throwable, String> = either {
  this@myFun.someMethod(...).bind() // Cannot access Receiver.someMethod, <this> is bound to EitherEffect
  ...
}
```

However, you should be able to simply call `someMethod` here without referencing `this`.

```kotlin
suspend fun Receiver.myFun(param: String): Either<Throwable, String> = either {
  someMethod(...).bind()
  ...
}
```

Hope that solves your issue.